# creating multiple SQS from main.tf configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have just updated my question to include my terragrunt.hcl that will call my main.tf to create the resources in different environment.I dont know how to replace the resources section of the policy that has `${aws_sqs_queue.Trail_SQS.arn}` because I need to have different names in their based on the environment I am working in and also I don't know how to represent the redrive_policy in my terragrunt.hcl.please guys i need some help.thanks inadvance

```
    Main.tf
    resource "aws_sqs_queue" "Trail_SQS"{

    name                       = var.aws_sqs
    visibility_timeout_seconds = var.visibility_timeout_seconds
    max_message_size           = var.max_message_size
    message_retention_seconds  = var.message_retention_seconds
    delay_seconds              = var.delay_seconds
    receive_wait_time_seconds  = var.receive_wait_time_seconds
    redrive_policy = jsonencode({
        deadLetterTargetArn    = aws_sqs_queue.Trail_SQS_DLQ.arn
        maxReceiveCount        = var.max_receive_count
    })

    }

    resource "aws_sqs_queue" "Trail_SQS_DLQ"{

    name                       = var.dead_letter_queue
    visibility_timeout_seconds = var.visibility_timeout_seconds
    max_message_size           = var.max_message_size
    message_retention_seconds  = var.message_retention_seconds
    delay_seconds              = var.delay_seconds
    receive_wait_time_seconds  = var.receive_wait_time_seconds

    }

    resource "aws_iam_role" "ronix_access_role" {
     name               = var.role_name
     description        = var.description
     assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.trust_relationship.json
    }

    data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ronix_policy_document"{
     statement{
     actions = [
      "sqs:DeleteMessage",
      "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
      "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
      "sqs:SendMessage",
      "sqs:SetQueueAttributes"
    ]
     effect = "Allow"
    resources =[
      "${aws_sqs_queue.Trail_SQS.arn}"
    ] }
   

    resource "aws_iam_policy" "ronix_policy" {
      name = "ronix_access_policy"
      description = "ronix policy to access SQS"
      policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.securonix_policy_document.json

    
    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ronix_policy_attachment" {
    policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ronix_policy.arn
    role       = aws_iam_role.ronix_access_role.id
}

    resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "trail_SQS_Policy" {
         queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.Trail_SQS.id

        policy = <<POLICY

{       "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Id": "sqspolicy",
        "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowSQSInvocation",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS":"*"},
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.Trail_SQS.arn}"

Terragrunt.hcl to call main.tf

    terraform {
         source = "../../../../..//module"
}


include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

inputs = {
  event_log_bucket_name = "trailbucket-sqs-logs"
  aws_sqs_queue_name               = "Trail_SQS"
  dead_letter_queue_name           = "Trail_SQS_DLQ"
  role_name                        = "ronix_access_role"
  description                      = "Role for ronix access"
  kms_key_arn                      = "ARN of the key"
}
}
```

Comment: Can you properly format your code? Also you haven't explained what's wrong with the code? What errors do you get?

Comment: This is also `terragrunt`? From what I see, the code is pure `terraform`.

Comment: @marcin.I just posted my terragrunt configuration to call the main.tf

Comment: I've updated my code and question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your setup but there are a few ways to do it.

1 - Using workspaces.

If you are using workspaces in terraform and let's say you have `dev` and `prod` as workspace, you can simply do it:

**locals.tf:**

```
locals {
  env = terraform.workspace
}
```

**sqs.tf:**

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "my_sqs" {
  name = "${local.env}-sqs"
  ...
}
```

It will create two sqs: `dev-sqs` and `prod-sqs` depending on each workspace you are in.

2 - If you are using environment variables in your setup, you need to send it to terraform like:

```
export TF_VAR_ENV=prod
```

Then your setup will be something like:

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "ENV" {
    type        = string
}
```

**sqs.tf**

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "my_sqs" {
  name = "${var.ENV}-sqs"
  ...
}
```